# Get the average for set of rows that has the same string value

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, data-science

I would like to know how can I get the average for all the rows that match the string name between positions **'Sample_Name'[11:16]** which are *P1_SUP, P1_0.2* and many other names in column 'Sample_Name'.

Bear in mind that there is no need if the last number of the string is different.

```
    D10     D50     D90     Sample_Name
1   4.46    19.81   45.32   TIGR01_P1_SUP_1
2   2.72    14.22   38.41   TIGR01_P1_SUP_1
3   2.3     12.05   27.58   TIGR01_P1_SUP_1
4   6.21    19.81   45.32   TIGR01_P1_SUP_2
5   3.78    16.78   32.55   TIGR01_P1_SUP_2
6   3.2     14.22   32.55   TIGR01_P1_0.2_1
7   2.72    12.05   27.58   TIGR01_P1_0.2_1
8   5.27    19.81   38.41   TIGR01_P1_0.2_2
9   3.78    14.22   32.55   TIGR01_P1_0.2_2
10  6.21    23.37   53.48   TIGR01_P1_0.4_1
.    .        .       .            .
.    .        .       .            .
.    .        .       .            .

expected output:

    Av_D10  Av_D50  Av_D90  Sample_Name
1    3.89   16.53   37.84    P1_SUP
2    3.74   15.07   32.77    P1_0.2
3    6.21   23.37   53.48    P1_0.4
.    .        .       .            .
.    .        .       .            .
.    .        .       .            .
```

EDIT:
After using @Chris code, there is an error :

> DataError: No numeric types to aggregate

I know it is because I am working with strings but can't get the mean for the desired data: D10, D50, D90.

Answer (score 1):

Use `pandas.Series.str` with `groupby`:

```
new_df = df.groupby(df["Sample_Name"].str[7:13]).mean()
print(new_df)
```

Or negative indexing:

```
new_df = df.groupby(df["Sample_Name"].str[-8:-2]).mean()
print(new_df)
```

Output:

```
                D10     D50      D90
Sample_Name                         
P1_0.2       3.7425  15.075  32.7725
P1_0.4       6.2100  23.370  53.4800
P1_SUP       3.8940  16.534  37.8360
```

Comment: And can I use the negative indexes? I've noticed that the names wont always match with the prefixed values(that's why I have put a wrong index for string[11:16] ).
But with negative indexes it will always be [-3:-8].

Comment: @MabyEsperanza You should be able to. Strings are basically similar as lists of chars.

Comment: @MabyEsperanza I've added negative indexing code as well (which is effectively the same)

Comment: @Chris Is there another line I should write? Because an error pops out saying:  `DataError: No numeric types to aggregate`